# Bootstrap npm install using package.json creating huge amount of files

Tags: css, frameworks, npm, less

I am currently trying bootstrap and attempting to use grunt to process my less source files and generate my css.

I have achieved this by installing bootstrap and grunt via npm and then copying the generated bootstrap folder over to my project folder.

myproject/bootstrap

I have then run **npm install** to setup grunt based on the bootstrap package.json.

Once the install has completed the boostrap directory contains over 20 thousand files.. is this normal?

I also wanted to change the directory from dist...to a css directory within the myproject folder so my dir structure would look something like this

myproject/src/bootstrap - All the src grunt/less files would go here.
myproject/public/css/ - This would be the new dist directory for the resultant css files.

However I have attempted to adjust the Gruntfile.js in order to change the dist directory... but there I have not manged to get it to export to anything outside of the source bootstrap directory?